# SUMIF with conditional INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, conditional-statements

I'm currently trying to produce a spreadsheet as follows, but on a much larger scale:

[image: Spreadsheet example]

On the left is a table detailing manager's monthly sales, and on the right is a simple summation. Not quite as simple as I thought though!

The formula I need to calculate a managers sales has to say:

- Sum 'Sold A' and 'Sold B' if the cell to the left contains the manager's name.

The general idea I came up with was, for H3 (`Bob`'s sales):

```
SUMIF(D3:E7, INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW();COLUMN()-1))....
```

How to make the INDIRECT conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest would be:

```
=SUMIF(C:C, G4, D:D) + SUMIF(C:C, G4, E:E)
```

Where G4 is in the second table and contains the manager's name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUMPRODUCT` to do that with a single function, i.e. in H3 copied down

`=SUMPRODUCT((C$3:C$7=G3)*D$3:E$7)`